# textarea in jquery mobile

Tags: android, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need to set jquery mobile textarea height in percentage in my android phonegap app.I have set the textarea height to percentage but it not changing.How to do this.Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
#textarea
{
   height:20%;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

```
textarea {
    height:50% !important;
}
```

But usually this is not enough because jQM content div will never take full height of available space if you only place textarea in it. So we need to make it take a whole page height.

Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BLcYP/